# Balance between fast and secure: time sensitive password encryption algorithm

Tags: algorithm, authentication, encryption, performance, client-server

I'm working on a client<>server multiplayer game. The authentication is done on the same server as all game logic etc. This means that my authentication password encryption algorithm can't take too much calculation time as it would delay all the other required actions. If many people would logon at the same time that would cause a noticeable delay when used with very strong encryption algorithms that take a lot of time to process.

This is why I am looking for a balance: an encryption algorithm that is still reliable and not easily crackable but fast enough to execute on the same server. What do you recommend?

Comment: You should make clear if you are looking for a cryptographic hash algorthim for hashing passwords, or a general cipher.  Also it sounds like you are writing authentication from scratch. Tread carefully and consider using mature examples that employ well-known cryptography methods to avoid many subtle pitfalls.

Comment: I'm talking about encryption on client side and then decryption on the server's side.

Comment: I don't see how that fits with the "authentication password encryption algorithm". You may want to elaborate a bit on how your protocol works.

Comment: I think what you want is probably a challenge-response protocol, that would potentially make the process faster since you don't need to setup a session secret and or setup the key scheduling (if applicable).

Comment: Do not design this from scratch.

Comment: I want to use an already existing encryption algorithm, so how am I designing this from scratch? I need to add somekind of code myself though to actually use this algorithm, right?

Comment: @Tom, just keep in mind that every line you add is a potential security hole. Using cryptography is not trivial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, to perform authentication, you don't need an an "encrypted" password; storing an encrypted password puts your users at risk and I strongly discourage it. Because users are ignorant, they are likely to use the same password for their bank account and your game. Help them stay safe by taking good care of that password.

Instead, store an irreversible "hash" of the password and a random "salt". There are many questions about how to do this on StackOverflow, and a couple of their answers are almost correct.

The part of your question that is unique is that you are specifically concerned with the performance of the authentication process. This is an interesting question, because a good password protection scheme is actually designed to be a little bit slow. This is to defeat an attacker who is trying to guess a password in an "offline" attack, where he can test billions of passwords. The slower the algorithm, the fewer attempts he can make.

The algorithm I recommend for protecting passwords is actually a key derivation algorithm called PBKDF2 (PBKDF1 would work also), which is described in PKCS #5. One of the tuning parameters of these algorithms is a number of iterations. You can profile the algorithm on your server, and adjust the number of iterations until you find a number that meets your performance requirements. Even my laptop can perform thousands of iterations per second, so I'd probably start with around 2000 and work from there.

If you are actually talking about encrypting all of the traffic between the client and server, use AES. It was selected because of its speed even though some other ciphers in the competition are probably more secure. Specifically, use an AES cipher suite in an SSL connection.

The expense of a secure connection is the key agreement (or key transport) that happens when the session is set up. The on-going encryption (and message integrity computation) adds very little overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Virtually any strength of AES, used properly, will probably suit your needs.
[You can also purchase a hardward card to radically accelerate AES.](http://www.hifn.com/SocMe/?id=705)

[Speed Comparison of Popular Crypto Algorithms](http://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html)

Comment: That name would suggest that it's used for one-way hashing? Not two-way encryption and decryption?